# How to make dropdown menu disappear after a certain amount of time JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a side menu that drops down when you hover over the Section One within the  tag. I want to know how to get the JavaScript code to repeat itself to check what state the list is in again after a certain amount of time so that the menu closes. Can anyone please help me?

HTML

```
   <div class = "sidebarwrap">
    <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#" onmouseover="toggle(this); return true;" onmouseout="timer()">Section One</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#" >link page</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" >link page</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" >link page</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" >link page</a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebarwrap{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}

.sidebarwrap ul{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background:white;
    padding:10px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-left:10px;
    list-style-type:none;
    border:1px dotted #0099CC;
    border-radius:100px/10px;
}

.sidebarwrap ul ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:none;
    border:0px dotted #0099CC;
    border-radius:20px/60px;
}

.sidebarwrap li li{
    list-style-type:circle;
    border:0px dotted #0099CC;
    border-radius:20px/60px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
cssNode.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
cssNode.setAttribute('type','text/css');
cssNode.setAttribute('href', 'javascript-overrides.css');
document.getElementsByTagName('head') [0].appendChild(cssNode);


function toggle(toggler) {

    if(document.getElementById){
        targetElement = toggler.nextSibling;

        if(targetElement.className == undefined){
        targetElement = toggler.nextSibling.nextSibling;
        }

        if (targetElement.style.display == "block")
        {
        targetElement.style.display = "none";
        }
        else
        {
        targetElement.style.display = "block";
        timer();
        }
    }
}

function timer(){
     var Time = setTimeout(function(){toggle(toggler)},1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the .hover() method in jQuery. Just bind to the link when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").hover(function () {
       $(this).next().slideDown(); 
    },
    function () {
        $(this).next().delay(1000).slideUp();
    });
});
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WFN6q/

Here is a working example in Vanilla JS:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onmouseover="showMenu(this)" onmouseout="hideMenu(this)">Section One </a>
        <ul>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Corresponding JS:

```
    function showMenu(myLink) {
        myLink.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hideMenu(myLink) {
        var ulElem = myLink.nextElementSibling;
        if (ulElement.style.display === 'block') {
            setTimeout(function () { myLink.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none' }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this works, you will run into issues with trying to click the sub menu items unless you are quick. You will probably need to add additional logic to the mouseout event to handle cases where the user is hovering over one of the sub menu items.

Comment: for hovering I'd recommend something like hoverIntent to handle that. You could write it yourself, but why? it's a small library that does only that.

Comment: I like this answer so I'm going to stop with my code, but I'd add that you still want to set up a global obj to hold your timers so that you don't have users setting off 4 timers within the span of 1s.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers I found them very useful, I found that this code is sufficient, as I can add more time to the setTimeout function.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a global timer obj. You can prevent multiple timers from executing by check the style of the display before the setTimeout. I have updated my code example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your code, you have onmouseout set to call timer(), which will create an extraneous timeout function that does not have `toggler` defined.  Further, your code will recourse indefinitely, ~every 1000ms.

You should define a global Timers variable to hold your timer references. That way this function can exit and you can cancel or otherwise manipulate the timer. As well, you can implement a Singleton model here and prevent you from having many many timers.

```
var Timers = {}; // create a Timers object to hold our timers.
function timer(target){
    Timers.sectionOne = setTimeout(function(){ toggle(target); }, 1000);
}
```

EDIT: I'd take this in addition to the method @Bic described, which is nicely elegant.